# Record video clip from webcam in Drupal 7 custom module

Tags: files

I want to capture the video clip from webcam in my own Drupal 7 custom module. Is there any way to capture the webcam and record the video clips in Drupal 7? Please, anyone can help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Media: Webcam](http://drupal.org/project/media_webcam)

> This project (still under active development) will add a Webcam
>   capture tool for video and images to FileField. Video requires a Red5
>   or Flash Media server to also be available; documentation for this
>   coming soon enough.

Browse the [`SOURCE`](http://drupalcode.org/project/media_webcam.git) to get some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks Nikhil.

Is it possible to do with Drupal 7? Because FileField module is not available for Drupal 7..

Comment: In D7 CCK is in core. So i think its possible with some effort.

Comment: I tried. but its not working. can you please help me on this?